# List changes value in for loops of python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a basic question regarding what a for loop does to a list in Python. I saw some related questions on the website, but somehow those examples are too complicated and I am still unable to solve my problem.

Consider the following code.

```
l=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for i in range(4):
    
    t=l
    print(t)
    print(l)
    del t[0]
```

I was expecting that in each iteration the first element of the list `t` is deleted, while the list `l` is unchanged and should remain to be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`. However, the out come is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

That is, not only the first element of `t` but also the first element of `l` is deleted in each iteration, as if `l` is locked to be `t`, rather than some external variable of the for loop.

Why is this so? And how can I modify the code so that only the first element of `t` is deleted, while `l` remains unchanged throughout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
l=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

for i in range(4):
    
    t=l.copy()
    print(t)
    print(l)
    del t[0]
```

While working with this list, when we assign a list to another variable. we actually create another reference of the same list. Therefore, there would be only one list in memory, which has two reference variable.